# Obtaining Previously Produced ID

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a new row into my MySQL table. I had this code working when I randomly generated the IDs, however when I changed the table properties so that the IDs are now auto increment fields, the code no longer works as the Ids are no longer known to the function.

Code Snippet:

```
def register():
#Insert Into Usertable
userInsertSQL="""INSERT INTO users (username,password,stakeholder) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
mycursor.execute(userInsertSQL,(inputedUsername.get(),inputedPassword.get(),inputedStakeholder.get()))
mydb.commit()
# Determine which table to place new user into
if inputedStakeholder.get() == "Employee":
    employeeInsertSQL="""INSERT INTO employee (firstname,secondname,gender,userID) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    mycursor.execute(employeeInsertSQL,(inputedFirstName.get(),inputedSecondName.get(),inputedGender.get(),userID))
```

Is there a method of attaining the userID produced in the first Insert statement without SELECTING the last column in the users table?

Comment: I would recommend using a stored procedure for the insert. You can then pass back `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to your python code. As a bonus, it can avoid SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function provided by MySQL:

```
if inputedStakeholder.get() == "Employee":
    employeeInsertSQL = """INSERT INTO employee (firstname,secondname,gender,userID)
                           SELECT %s, %s, %s, LAST_INSERT_ID()"""
    mycursor.execute(inputedFirstName.get(), inputedSecondName.get(),
        inputedGender.get())
```

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html), you will find that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last generated auto increment value in a table.  So long as you are just using a single connection for your Python script, and no other threads are sharing that connection, the above approach should work.